# How to backup bookmarks on Safari

Tags: macos, icloud, bookmarks

Before reinstalling OS X, I want to know is it possible to use native capabilities to backup my bookmarks using iCloud, without install some plugins like a Xmarks?  I know manual way to export bookmarks via Safari menu, but this is inconvenient.

Comment: Did you enable Bookmarks in iCloud already?

Comment: Since it is so important to you make a copy of the Bookmarks.plist file (located in Safari library), I know it looks like garbage but all the info is there, so just in case .)

Answer (score 2):

If you enabled iCloud for Safari in the iCloud settings, your bookmarks are already stored in the Cloud.

Comment: Yes in my preferences iCloud for Safari was enabled. But I want to ensure, because these bookmarks very valuable for me.

Comment: The only way to test it is to check another device for example an iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

You could always export your bookmarks into an html file.  I do this from time to time.  Simply go to the File Menu and select "Export Bookmarks".

Under the file menu there is also an Import Bookmarks in case your bookmarks were ever lost.